# What are some real world examples of a 2d data set where agglomerative methods work and K means doesnt? (for two real groups of data)

Tags: data

What is 2D dataset with two real groups of data where an agglomerative clustering method will be able to cluster the data correctly, and K-means will not?

I thought about a data set that would look like the figure below, but still I can't think of any real world features that would graph such a data set.
[image]

Comment: the term "real" is misleading. In a world where increasingly digtal data are gathered almost all data can be pointed to some real digital scenario